# rails - comparing two values to see if they are equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I want to be able to found out if two values are equal in a controller action.

```
def completed
  @meeting = Meeting.find(params[:id])
  if @meeting.day_of_meeting == @meeting.days
    @meeting.update_attribute(:day_of_meeting, '1')
    redirect_to :back
  else
    @meeting.increment!
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

The line I have in question is:

```
if @meeting.day_of_meeting == @meeting.days
```

When I run it, it never seems to be able to validate that both those fields are equal and just increments the day_of_meeting field.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE

In the model increment!

```
def increment!
  update_attribute(:day_of_meeting, day_of_meeting + 1)
end
```

Essentially, @meeting.day_of_meeting is a ticker that when equaled to @meeting.day, I want @meeting.day_of_workout to be reset back to '1'. What is happening is @meeting.day_of_meeting never resets and continues to increment. Both values are integers.

Comment: You're gonna have to provide more context... `@meeting.day_of_meeting` doesn't seem like it should ever equal somethine called `@meeting.days`...  Maybe days is an array, and you seeing if the array includes day_of_meeting or something?

Comment: It's not an array. They are two columns in the same table that when equaled to each, need the day_of_meeting to be reset back to '1'.

Comment: Are they both of the same type (e.g. integers or strings)?  This seems like it'd be fairly straight forward to troubleshoot in the console?

Comment: I updated the question. Hopefully it's a little clearer.

Comment: It's another question of yours that rises a red flag for me. You ask for a VERY strange things and I have a gut feeling this could be done better (from Rails and design perspective). Maybe try asking a more generic question and ping me - I will be glad to help!

Comment: Thank you. I definitely will bug you soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more code, I'm guessing that either @meeting.day_of_meeting or @meeting.days maybe a string.

```
@meeting.day_of_meeting == @meeting.days.to_i
```

assuming @meeting.days is a string, you can convert to integer and compare.

Comment: Absolutely correct. I had checked for this earlier but for some reason my eyes tricked me into thinking both were stored as integers. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the two lists have the same contents, but in a different order, then not exactly the same. So try:

```
@meeting.day_of_meeting.sort == @meeting.days.sort
```